# What is the meaning of these number in Odoo model?

Tags: python, model, odoo-10

I'm using Odoo to manage products
I wonder that what is the purpose of these numbers?

```
product.write({
                  'attribute_line_ids': [(0, 0, {
                      'attribute_id': attribute_id,
                      'value_ids': [(4, value_id)],
                    })]
                })
```

0, 0...
4, value_id
Why we have to add them before the main number?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find out the answer!

List item

- (0, 0, { values }) link to a new record that needs to be created with
  the given values dictionary
- (1, ID, { values }) update the linked record with id = ID (write
  values on it)
- (2, ID) remove and delete the linked record with id = ID (calls
  unlink on ID, that will delete the object completely, and the link to
  it as well)
- (3, ID) cut the link to the linked record with id = ID (delete the
  relationship between the two objects but does not delete the target
  object itself)
- (4, ID) link to existing record with id = ID (adds a relationship)
- (5) unlink all (like using (3,ID) for all linked records)
- (6, 0, [IDs]) replace the list of linked IDs (like using (5) then
  (4,ID) for each ID in the list of IDs)